# ActiveRecord query multiple with AND instead of OR on has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to setup a search for my Rails app.

There are 2 models with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship:

```
class Post
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag
  has_and_belongs_to_many :post
end
```

To confirm, here are the tables:

```
create_table "posts" do |t|
  t.bigint "user_id"
  t.string "title"
  ...
end

create_table "tags" do |t|
  t.string "name"
end

create_table "tags_posts", id: false do |t|
  t.bigint "post_id", null: false
  t.bigint "tag_id", null: false
  t.index ["post_id", "tag_id"]
  t.index ["tag_id", "post_id"]
end
```

I want to make an AND query: `All POSTS that have TAGS 1, 2, AND 3`.

The closest I've gotten is this simple query, but it returns `OR` instead of `AND` - all the posts that have 1 of those 3 tags.
`Post.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: [1, 2, 3] })`.

How do I get a query like this where can I easily add N number of Tag IDs to the ActiveRecord query and have it be an `AND` query.

Bonus question - is there any way to add a parameter where it returns Posts where at least M number of tags exist on the Post. So `ALL POSTS that have AT LEAST 2 TAGS of 1, 2, AND 3`?

#### Update

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7994175/659820

To translate:

```
Post.find_by_sql("
  SELECT p.* FROM posts p,
    post_tags pt1,
    post_tags pt2,
    tags t1,
    tags t2
  WHERE
    p.id = pt1.post_id
  AND t1.id = 4
  AND t1.id = pt1.post_tag_id
  AND p.id = pt2.post_id
  AND t2.id = 11
  AND t2.id = pt2.post_tag_id
")
```

1. Is this is the most efficient way to accomplish this?
2. Bonus question still unanswered - give some M matches for the N tags provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using join table. In order to fetch the correct posts with the join table, we need to look at the count of the posts matching the condition:

```
tag_ids = [1, 2, 3] # You can use tag name instead of id
Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: tag_ids }).group(:id).having("count(*) = ?", tag_ids.size)
```

**UPDATE**

This should work:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  def self.tagged_with(post_tags, m = nil)
    m ||= post_tags.size
    Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: post_tags }).group(:id).having("count(*) >= ?", m)
  end
end

tag_ids = [1, 2, 3]
Post.tagged_with(tag_ids)
#=> Returns posts which has all tags.
Post.tagged_with(tag_ids, 2)
#=> Returns posts which has at least two of given tags.
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Any idea if my "bonus question" is possible?

Comment: Ah of course, your initial answer made that adjustment obvious. Much appreciated, demir!